# Catch the IpAddress from ping host c#

Tags: c#, networking, ping

I want to ask if it is possible to get the IpAddress from the ping host. So if someone pings my computer I know their IpAddress.

My code looks like this:

```cs
while (true)
{
    Socket icmpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
    icmpListener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("564.89.556.5"), 0));
    icmpListener.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 });
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    int bytesRead = icmpListener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref remoteEndPoint);
    string text = "ICMPListener received " + bytesRead + " from " + remoteEndPoint;
    Console.WriteLine(text);                
}
```

After the code ran and someone pings me I know which ip was pinged put not the one from the host of the ping. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Is not `remoteEndPoint` updated with the remote address after receiving the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var ip = icmpListener.RemoteEndPoint;
```

> > If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, the RemoteEndPoint property gets the EndPoint that contains the remote IP address and port number to which the Socket is connected. If you are using a connectionless protocol, RemoteEndPoint contains the default remote IP address and port number with which the Socket will communicate. You must cast this EndPoint to an IPEndPoint before retrieving any information. You can then call the IPEndPoint.Address method to retrieve the remote IPAddress, and the IPEndPoint.Port method to retrieve the remote port number.

---

[image]

When using cmd to ping a machine (`ping 127.0.0.1`), you are pinging that maching with the **default port of 80**

```
Socket icmpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
        icmpListener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80));
        icmpListener.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 });
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            int bytesRead = icmpListener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref remoteEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("ICMPListener received " + bytesRead + " from " + remoteEndPoint);
        }
```

**Before you do anything, Open `CMD` as Administrator then type the following command: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="All ICMP v4" dir=in action=allow protocol=icmpv4:any,any`  This will allow the firewall rule to allow ICMP Port Unreachable packets to be received.**

## And Don't Forget To Run the C# program as Administrator

Comment: Could you send me some source Code? i have no idea how and where to Change my Code.

Comment: thanks @adola . But there is a Problem. It sas "A request to send or receive data was prevented, because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was specified" . Wel i think there is a Problem because the ping is so short so if i want to get the RemoteEndPoit the host already closed the Connection. Do you know a way how to fix that?

Comment: by the way @adola how many of my questions did you already awnsered? Thanks alot!

Comment: @jakob Thank you! Anyway, I have some questions to ask: 1) which line causes the error 2) Have you ever thought about working with tcp instead of icmp. TCP is better and can be used for pinging,making HTTP request and more! (I can provide some code for pinging if you want) 3) what code do you use to connect (I am using cmd with the ping command). 4.) what are you constructing (this will help me understand your code) Sorry if it's too much to ask.

Comment: There is a class in C# built for Pinging. Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well i worked a lott with tcp protocoll but what i want to make here is different. i want to know when someone is pinging me via cmd. I am working on a Programm i want to use like a ddos protection. If you want to ask why i dont use usual tools , I want to learn and not just use the Tools odther People wrote for me.

Comment: 1)      string text = "ICMPListener received " + bytesRead + " from " + icmpListener.RemoteEndPoint

Comment: @jakob Ok, I'll have to do more testing.

Comment: @jakob I am done (check my code again)! I tested myself and It worked! Make sure to run your program as Administrator.

Comment: yes! Thank you! do you know why it now works but the time before not?

Comment: you now awnsered 75% of all my questions. XD thanks for that. Is it possible to add you as a friend , follow your account or some Thing like that?

Comment: @jakob I don't have social media, but we can discuss in the chat here in stackExchange.. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145535/discussion-between-adola-and-jakob